# Answering a Query in C, after perfoming system call

Tags: c

I did an application that create a partintion and format the disk using system calls...

In the middle of the process there is a query asking to type the size of the disk... What can i do in my application in order to automaticly answer that query??

can you please help me?

Comment: Are you using actual system calls (function calls in the OS) or are you calling command line tools?

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible with, for instance [libexpect](http://expect.nist.gov/) but I never tried it (but Google found what seems to be a [good example](http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=3816)). On my Debian machine, `man libexpect` says:

```
    libexpect - programmed dialogue library with interactive programs

    This  library  contains functions that allow Expect to be used as a Tcl
    extension or to be used directly from C or C++ (without  Tcl).
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your operating system (windows can do it for instance) you can have the stdin for the programmed redirected to come from an output of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use system() do run utilities like **expect** to control the process

Answer (score -1):

fortunately, There is nothing you can do. :)

Comment: Why do you say so? Why "fortunately"? Anyway, it is false, there are many ways to talk with a program from another program.